# Efficient image scaling in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, opengl-es, openvg

How to scale image (`Bitmap`/`EncodedImage`) efficiently in Blackberry (using `OpenVG`/`OpenGL` if hardware acceleration supported). Can something like `VGField`/`GLField` be used to achieve that?

I have already tried `Bitmap.scaleInto(...)`, `EncodedImage.scaleImage32(..)` and some naive algorithms (raw data manipulation). Also I can't use `ZoomScreen` because it is not possible (?) to change the image of an `ZoomScreen` instance dynamically.

Need some idea about how the default image viewer application in BlackBerry device (e.g. Torch 9800) performs smooth pinch zooming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual technique is:

- Step 1: scale the current thumbnail, so you get a rather blocky looking image, but has the advantage of working nearly instantaneously.
- Step 2: kick off the higher resolution image decoder on a separate thread.  When it is done, it sends the newly decoded image back to the UI thread to replace the approximate image that was used from step 1.

Comment: Thank you. Step 1 is okay, Step 2 also, but the problem is in Step 2, I want a really fast image scaling routine.